# How to use Underscore templates instead of Jade in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, underscore.js, pug

I don't want to use the Jade templating engine that comes by default with Express. I tried to follow this guide but it fails:

http://blog.luksidadi.com/expressjs-underscore-template/

The error in question is:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: callback function required
    at Function.engine (/home/me/blog/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:173:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tk/blog/app.js:28:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

I get this when I try to start the server with:

```
node app.js
```

How to solve this?

**app.js:**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  //app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

// Add these lines to register underscore template
var _ = require('underscore');
app.engine('.html', {
  compile: function(str, options){
    var compiled = require('underscore').template(str);
    return function(locals) {
        return compiled(locals);
    };
  }
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

**routes/index.js:**

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index.html', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

**layout.html:**

```
< html >
  < head >
    < title ><%=title%>< /title >
  < /head >
  < body >
  <%=body%>
  < /body >
< /html >
```

**index.html:**

```
Hello world
```

Comment: More context, please. Stack traces are usually useless without code with which to reference them.

Comment: @JackManey Updated the question to include code. I pretty much just followed the guide on that link.

Comment: So you can try `ejs`, `jshtml` or `hogan.js`?

Answer (score 5):

Use [consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js) to convert Underscore's template functions to accept the format Express requires in 3.x `(path[, locals], callback)`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are calling `app.engine` with an extension name and an object whereas it takes a function as second parameter (see [source documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L156)).

This function has 3 parameters : the path to the file, options and the callback.

As, written in the [documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L160), it's advised to use `consolidate.js` as an helper to use template engines that are not express friendly.

Here a simple integration of `consolidate.js` quoted from its [README](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js#express-3x-example) and adapted to use underscore:

```
// assign the swig engine to .html files
app.engine('html', cons.underscore);

// set .html as the default extension 
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Also, I don't know how to handle your layout.html with underscore under Express, I don't think it's possible out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

```
var cons = require('consolidate');
```

// view engine setup

```
app.engine('html',cons.underscore);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

in terminal

```
npm install consolidate --save
```